# JavaScript | Object: Get Property Ninja Move

Tags: javascript, object, collections, getter

#### Looking for a native method for pulling a value off of a key in an object...

I have a collection which could look like the following:

```
[ { id: '998' }, { id: '997' }, { id: '996' } ]
```

I would like to do similar to the following:

```
var ids = collection.map(Object.getMyProperty.bind(this, 'id'));
```

Result:

```
[ '998', '997', '996' ]
```

Needless to say, we could write an iterator for this, but I'm looking for something a little more compact. I say 'ninja move' to mean something very creative, such as `Array.apply(null, { length: 3 });` which results in an array of length 3 -- or other approaches from Resig's Secrets... book.

Anyone have any ideas on a minimalistic, compact, quick way of accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
var ids = [{id: '998'}, {id: '997'}, {id: '996'}].map(o => o.id);
```

```js
var ids = [{id: '998'}, {id: '997'}, {id: '996'}].map(o => o.id);
console.log(ids);
```

Comment: this exactly i was wrinting

Comment: `o => o.id` where can we read about it? haven't see it before in JS

Comment: @AndrewEvt [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) Same as `function(o) { return o.id; }`

Comment: To get the IDs in Number format, use `.map(o => +o.id);`

Answer (score 2):

`var newArray = array.map(function(i) { return i.id; });`

fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hqcbpwac/